# How to split a fraction into two integers c++

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment.  I need to have the user input a fraction in `#/#` format . How can I set the top and bottom to two separate variables?

Here's a chunk of code I've tried, but I keep getting nothing for the second variable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string firstFraction;

    cout << "Enter your first real Fraction: " << endl;
    firstFraction = cin.get();

    string delimiter = "/";

    string numerator = firstFraction.substr(0,firstFraction.find(delimiter));

    size_t pos = firstFraction.find("/");
    string denominator = firstFraction.substr(pos); 

    cout << numerator << " / " << denominator << endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you paste in your code correctly. You're missing the starts and end, along with the indentation for formatting.

Comment: Does `string denominator = firstFraction.substr(pos); ` really make sense to you? If so, could you explain what you think it does?

Comment: ^ You're missing a declaration of `firstFraction`. You can [edit] your question to include additional information. Also, we have to assume that `string` is indeed a `std::string`

Comment: i'm very new to c++ and this site as well. i apologize for any incorrect formatting. I've tried a bunch of stuff but this is just what gives me the closest result to what I'm looking for but not quite right. all i want is to set the top and bottom numbers of the fraction to two separate variable.

Comment: Take a look at [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and [`std::getline(stream, variable, '/')`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Comment: @Tas Obviously namespaces are useless :P I guess that's why it seems that the first thing they teach people is how to avoid them. | @jj [Avoid `using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string fraction;

    cout << "Enter your first real Fraction: " << endl;
    getline(cin, fraction);

    istringstream iss(fraction);

    string numerator, denominator;
    getline(iss, numerator, '/');
    getline(iss, denominator);

    cout << numerator << " / " << denominator << endl;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One possible tweak (in case abstract values are not desired): An `isdigit` test to make sure numerator and denominator are indeed numbers.

Comment: @user4581301: using `operator>>` and failure tests is a better way to handle that.

Comment: I was able to figure it out differently but this was very helpful thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
firstFraction = cin.get();
```

Print `firstFraction` after this line and see whether it contains what you thought it contains. Looking in [the reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) (something you should be doing!) ...

> [..] Reads one character and returns it if available. [..]

... we learn that you're only reading a *single* character (of unformatted input). How do you intend to split the resulting (single character) string?

There are multiple ways of doing it correctly, which one to choose depends a lot on your needs. A short, non-complete list:

- `std::getline` the whole line, and then searching for `/` within it
- `std::getline` until the next `/`, `std::getline` until end of line. (I don't really recommend this)
- Formatted input, [for example](http://ideone.com/VlcpcK) :

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main() {
      unsigned int nominator, denominator;
      char sep;
      cin >> nominator >> sep >> denominator;

      if (!cin || sep != '/') {
          cerr << "Well... you know, that failed somehow." << endl;
          return 1;
      }
      cout << "Fraction: " << nominator << "/" << denominator << endl;
      return 0;
  }
  ```

  Though this also allows input like

  ```
  3   / 4
  ```

  and

  ```
  3
  /
  4
  ```

And of course, you should abstract this, e.g. make a `fraction` class, and write a (member) function `read_fraction` (and also provide a suitable `operator>>` if you want).

Answer (score 0):

This could be as simple as

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
//using namespace std; dangerous! Use with caution

int main()
{
    int num; // want a number as numerator
    int denom; // and a number as denomenator
    char divsign; // and a character to hold the / 

    std::cout << "Enter your first real Fraction: " << std::endl;
    // user input contains at least a numerator a / and a denominator
    // anything less fails. anything more will slip through. If this is a
    // problem, add another >> to see if there is more in the stream
    if (std::cin >> num >> divsign >> denom && // all input read successfully
        divsign == '/') // and the division operator was present
    { // got what we need. Print it.
        std::cout << num << " / " << denom << std::endl;
    }
    else
    { // bad input. insult user.
        std::cout << "Bogus user input. No fraction for you" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It has a number of potential failure cases, such as:

```
999999999999 / 2
Bogus user input. No fraction for you
```

Integer overflow. The input was too big. And

```
1/1dfjklghaljkgadlfhjgklahd
1 / 1
```

Crap after the last character